# Type 'GrpcObject' has no construct signatures _ typescript grpc

Tags: typescript, grpc-js

I am new in ts . I am working with nest. I am trying to use my grpc-client I wrote with js . but when I try to export my grpc service object I get this error:

```
import {loadPackageDefinition,credentials} from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import {loadSync} from '@grpc/proto-loader';

const packageDefinition = loadSync(`${__dirname}/protos/main.proto`, {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true,
    arrays: true
});


let { AuthService } = loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition) ;

 export const auth_client = new AuthService(`localhost:${process.env.auth_grpc_port?process.env.auth_grpc_port:30030}`,credentials.createInsecure());
```

error :

> src/lib/grpc.client.ts:16:34 - error TS2351: This expression is not
> constructable.   Not all constituents of type 'GrpcObject |
> ServiceClientConstructor | ProtobufTypeDefinition' are constructable.
> Type 'GrpcObject' has no construct signatures.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the TypeScript types for the object output by `loadPackageDefinition` are too generic to be used that way effectively. One solution would be to use the TypeScript generator distributed with `@grpc/proto-loader` version 0.6.x to generate TypeScript types for your proto files. Then you can use a type assertion to make the output of `loadPackageDefinition` have a specific structure that reflects your proto files.